# A java program to find out the frequrncy of a word using Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, frequency

Can any one tell me that how to use Scanner Class of Java to find the frequency of a word in a sentence.

I am confused as to enter a line in java i have to use nextInt() function but to compare need it to convert in char so how to do so.

For example:-

I enter on terminal window(Giving Input)

This is my cat.

Now i have to find the FREGUENCY of word "this" in the above sentence. Please can you give me some idea.REMEMBER THE RESTRICTION IMPOSED ON IT IS I HAVE TO USE ONLY SCANNER CLASS OF JAVA LIBRARY

PROGRAMME USING STREAM READER IS AS FOLLOWS-

```
import java.io.*;

class FrequencyCount
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        String s=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter substring: ");    
        String sub=br.readLine();

        int ind,count=0;
        for(int i=0; i+sub.length()<=s.length(); i++)
        //i+sub.length() is used to reduce comparisions  
        {
            ind=s.indexOf(sub,i);
            if(ind>=0)
            {
                count++;
                i=ind;
                ind=-1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Occurence of '"+sub+"' in String is "+count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternative solution using pattern

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaApplication20 {

   public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence:\t");
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a word:\t");
    String word = scanner.nextLine();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()){
        count +=1;
    }    
    System.out.println("in your sentence the frequency of \""+word+"\" is:\t" + count);      
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this.

```
public class JavaApplication20 {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence:\t");
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a word:\t");
    String word = scanner.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    while (!sentence.equals("")){
        if(sentence.contains(word)){ // check if the word is in the sentence; if yes cut the sentence at the index of the first appearance of the word plus word length 
                                     // then check the rest of the sentence for more appearances 
            sentence = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(word)+word.length());
            count++;
        }
        else{
            sentence = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("in your sentence the frequency of \""+word+"\" is:\t" + count);      
  }    
}
```

Comment: You can apply pattern and use method mathc() which return MatchResult, there you can find count

Comment: @ema thank you for the hint. I was trying to keep it simple and understandable. I will add another answer as alternative using pattern.

Comment: @Uzochi thank you very much But i wanted to ask what i will do to terminate this programm as soon as I end string with a period(.) I know about delimiters but how to use it in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter a String too using Scanner Class . Here is your code that i modified , and it working . `

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
    String s=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter substring: ");    
    String sub=in.nextLine();

    int ind,count=0;
    for(int i=0; i+sub.length()<=s.length(); i++)
    //i+sub.length() is used to reduce comparisions  
    {
        ind=s.indexOf(sub,i);
        if(ind>=0)
        {
            count++;
            i=ind;
            ind=-1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Occurence of '"+sub+"' in String is "+count);
}
```

The `nextLine()` method of Scanner class let you input Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen to @Uzochi. His answers may work, but they're way too complicated and may actually slow your program down.

For the Scanner class, there are multiple ways of reading in numbers or text:

`nextInt()` - scans in the next integer value

`nextDouble()` - scans in the next double value

`nextLine()` - scans in the next line of text

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html - scroll down to method summary, and in the middle of all of the methods, you will find all of the "next" methods.

Note that there is a small bug with Scanner (at least with the last time I used it). Say you're using a Scanner called `scan`. If you call

```
scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

(which reads in an integer and then a line of text), your Scanner will skip the call to `nextLine()`. This is a small bug that can easily be fixed by adding another `nextLine()`. It will catch the second nextLine.

In response to @Uzochi, there is a much simpler solution to your algorithm. Your algorithm is actually faster than his, although there are some small things that could make your program run a tiny bit faster:

1) Use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. Your use of `indexOf()` makes the current index of the String s you're at skip forward a lot, so there's virtually no point in having a `for` loop. You can easily change it into a `while` loop. Your conditions would be to keep checking if `indexOf()` returns a non-negative value (-1 means there is no value), and you increment that index value by 1 (like the for loop does automatically).

2) Smaller thing - you don't need the line:

```
ind=-1;
```

Your current code will always modify ind before it hits that `if` statement, so there is virtually no reason to have this line in the program.

EDIT - @Uzochi may be using Java's built in libraries, but for a beginner like OP, you should be learning how to use for and while loops to efficiently write code.